# Using SQlite3 in PHP how to count the number of rows in a result set?

Tags: php, count, sqlite

currently I am using:

```
$result = new SQLite3(sprintf("users/USERIDS_DB.sqlite"));

$numRows = $result->exec ("SELECT count(*) FROM USERIDS");

echo sprintf("the number of rows are: %d", $numRows);
```

but the result is 1 when it should be 6 (the number of rows I created using firefox sqlite3 addon)

Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.exec.php):

> *public bool SQLite3::exec  (  string $query  )*
>
> Executes a **result-less** query against a given database.

This methods returns a boolean, not a result set. When you convert `true` to an integer it will become `1`.

You should use [`SQLite3::query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.query.php). Example (untested):

```
$rows = $result->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM USERIDS");
$row = $rows->fetchArray();
$numRows = $row['count'];
```

---

Btw, naming the instance of the SQLite3 class `$result` can be misleading (especially in a DB environment). I would call it `$db` or `$connection`.

Comment: should be $numRows = $row['COUNT(*)'];

Comment: @Unplug: No, since the result of `COUNT(*)` is stored in `count`: `COUNT(*) as count`.

Comment: `querySingle()` is also a good alternative: `$numRows = $db->querySingle("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM USERIDS");`

Comment: This counts the number of records in the database, not the number in the result.

Answer (score 24):

```
$db = new SQLite3('filename.db3');
$count = $db->querySingle("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM tablename");
echo $count;
```

Comment: This counts the number of records in the database, not the number of rows in the result.

Answer (score 5):

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM db_name")
$row=$result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
    // check for empty result
    if ($row != false) {
      // do something here if record exists
    }
```

Comment: This checks if there is a valid result, not how many of them.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    function SqliteNumRows($query){
        $numRows = 0;
        while($rows = $query->fetchArray()){
            ++$numRows;
        }
        return $numRows;
    }
?>
```

This really helped me it works actually you may try it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working way to get the number of rows since neither `sqlite_num_rows($result)` nor `$result->numRows()` works on SQLite3:

```
<?php
     $db = new SQLite3('database.db');

    $results = $db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT `id`,* FROM `table` ORDER BY `id` ASC);');
        while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
           echo $row["COUNT(*)"];
        }
?>
```

Comment: This counts the number of records in the database, not the number in the result.

Answer (score 0):

It's have benefit, when you have conditions in the count `select` query:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `tablename` WHERE `foo`=:foo');
$stmt->bindValue(':foo', $foo);
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
echo $count;
```

Comment: This counts the number of records in the database, not the number in the result.

Comment: @Joeri Based on the conditions specified in the `WHERE` query, the number of database records is the same as the return result.

Comment: @Nabi-k-a-z No. You cannot know if someone added to, or removed from the database after you got your results. The question is to count the results, not to count what currently is in the database.

Comment: @Joeri You are logically right, but technically what happens is the same because counting lines happens in an instant. Whether you count them directly in the query or return the results and count them. They do not matter because it happens in a fast moment. In any case, if you are obsessed with the subject, you can do a simple `SELECT` query and then `count()` function the number of results.

Comment: @Nabi-k-a-z I'm not obsessed, I'm in an environment more then one service can access the database. And if you don't get your data in a blocking transaction then data can change in between two queries. Let's hope so, why else use a database. Not even mentioning how slow 2 queries are instead of one. And, answers on stackoverflow should answer the question. The question explicit mentions result set, so technically you are just wrong.

Comment: @Joeri I understand what you mean, the issue you are raising is a common and correct issue. But that's not the point of this question. Because the questioner did not mention such a challenge and it is clear that it is a mistake to use the `exec` function whose return is `boolean` and therefore the user receives the number `1`. so,this is just a bug in the misuse of the function. This is explained in more detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2586771/1407491
In proving what the questioner really meant. I would like to draw your attention to green tick that received the same answer from him.