# Cannot redirect to a php page after login

Tags: php, html, authentication, sqlite

Just noticed that after login with user and password I'm never redirected to welcome.php page, nevertheless that it looks the input is accepted :(

Any ideas?
The error is:
No such file or directory

That's the code
index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();

include "functions.php";

$database = "/mnt/www/zzz/summer.db"; // Database name
$table = "login"; // Table name
$logged = ""; // Logged status
// Open database
$opendb = new SQLite3($database);
$finduser = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE UserName='".$username."'";
$finduserandpass = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE UserName = '".$username."' AND Password = '".$password."'";

if($_POST['submit'])
{
  $username = protect($_POST['username']);
  $password = protect($_POST['password']);
  if(!$username || !$password)
  {
        echo "Username and password are required!";
  }
  else
  {
        $results = $opendb->query($finduser) or die("Query error");
        // numColumns() is counting table row
    $count = $results->numColumns();
    if($count == 0)
    {
      echo "The ussername does not exist!";
    }
    else
    {
            $count = $results->numColumns();
      if($num == 0)
      {
        echo "Wrong password!";
      }
      else
      {

        $results2 = $opendb->query($finduserandpass) or die("Query error");
        $row = $finduserandpass->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
                if($row['E_mail'] == NULL)
                {
                    echo "Your account is not yet activated!";
                }
                else
        {

                    $_SESSION['$username'] = $logged;
                    echo "Welcome!";
                    $time = date($logged)+60;
                    //redirect to the welcome page
                    header('Location: welcome.php');
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>
Title of the document
</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {background-color:teal;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td>Username:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
<td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

functions.php

```
<?php

function protect($mystring)
{
    $string = trim(strip_tags(addslashes($mystring)));
    return $mystring;
}

?>
```

welcome.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>
Summer Project Control Panel
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['$username'])
{
    header("Location: index.php");
}
else
{
  $currentUser = $_SESSION['username'];
  $message = '<p>Welcome, ' . ucfirst($currentUser) . '!</p>';
  echo $message;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's in login.php, I take it that's where you do the redirecting?

Comment: lol, yeah. Noticed that and fixed the `form action = "index.php"` but now it prints WRONG PASSWORD even when I provided the correct ones(in this case admin/admin).

Comment: I've added an answer with the 3 most obvious issues, that should get you on your way a little more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wrong password bit is because you are checking a non existent variable `$num` - the first time this appears is in your `if` statement

I think you also want `numrows` not `numcolumns` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-num-rows.php

Lastly, you'll need to remove the `echo` statement before your redirect, it'll cause you problems, and wont be seen by the user anyway as you are sending them to a different page.

Comment: I'm using SQLite3 and can't find the function in http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php

Comment: looks like you'll need to manually count with the query, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586598/using-sqlite3-in-php-how-to-count-the-number-of-rows-in-a-result-set

Answer (score 4):

Don't echo or print anything before sending headers.  Try commenting out the line `echo "Welcome!";`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect user, don't output anything, or else redirects would not work.
Just remove the echo statement and it should work fine.