# How to write this SQL query using having clause?

Tags: sql, having-clause

My database schema is like following

table - X has following 3 columns docid(document id), terms(terms in document), count(number of terms of occurence of the term for specific docid)

```
docid
terms
count
```

How to extract the information as for the following
The number of docid where sum of total words is more than 300 including duplicate words.

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
SELECT term, SUM(count) AS Totalwords
FROM tablex
GROUP BY  term
HAVING SUM(count) > 300
```

---

**Update**: Try this:

```
SELECT docid, SUM(count)
FROM tablex
GROUP BY docid
HAVING SUM(count) > 300;
```

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af3ad/2).

Comment: we don't need to take care of docid? because ultimately we have to find the total documents which has more than 300 words

Comment: @SurjyaNarayanaPadhi - Isn't the docid is a primary key in that table? What should be the grouped by column? is it `docid`? can you please show some sample data and the desired output?

Comment: the schema is like this - CREATE TABLE Frequency (
docid VARCHAR(255),
term VARCHAR(255),
count int,
PRIMARY KEY(docid, term));

Comment: the schema is like this - CREATE TABLE Frequency (
docid VARCHAR(255),
term VARCHAR(255),
count int,
PRIMARY KEY(docid, term));

Comment: sample data - 9988_txt_interest|funds|1
9988_txt_interest|6316|1
9988_txt_interest|york|2
9988_txt_interest|said|1
9988_txt_interest|sets|1
9988_txt_interest|time|1

Comment: desired output will be tuples of docid and count(which is total words in this document)

Comment: @SurjyaNarayanaPadhi See my update. It should work fine. Try it and let me know.

Comment: thanks a lot. It worked. Just little bit more help i need. How can i get the count of the rows printed in the query result.

Comment: @SurjyaNarayanaPadhi What RDBMS you are using? and what are you using to execute the query? do you execute it from a fron end application like php or c# or directly in the database management studio?

Comment: I am using sqlite3. I am sending the queries from PHP.

Comment: @SurjyaNarayanaPadhi - See [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2586771/722783), it might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
SELECT docid,SUM(COUNT) AS CNT
FROM X
GROUP BY docid
HAVING SUM(count) > 300
```