# PHP/Sqlite3: Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlite_num_rows()

Tags: php, sqlite

I am getting this error when I call the function `sqlite_num_rows`. It must not be dependency issue since other Sqlite functions are working. I'm able to open connection and get data from DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative to info on php.net

> neither of "sqlite_num_rows($result)" and "$result->numRows()" is not
> working on SQLite3 ! you should use this way:

```
<?php
 $db = new SQLite3('databasename.db'); 
 $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users"); 
 $rows = count ($result); 
 echo "Number of rows: $rows";
```

[Click me](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-num-rows.php#115230)

Comment: This solution doesn't work as it will always return one. The linked user contributed note is also heavily downvoted for being misleading.

Comment: When I've faced the same problem, info from php.net helped me to solve the problem. I don't remember my variant of code snippet, so if people say "it don't work" I should agree. Maybe this answer will help somebody: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11589902/1203805

Answer (score 2):

4 Years late but i had the same issue so here is my Solution for anyone that has the same problem

```
//$db is the database handle
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table_name");
$rows = 0; //set row counter to 0
while($row = $result->fetchArray()) {
    $rows += 1; //+1 to the counter per row in result
}
```